# A question on grammar in relation to pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns

- *But he insisted on going, him being a tenacious problem solver.*

I can intuit that "him" sounds more natural here than "he".
I want to know why this is so.

Comment: I've deleted other comments here, but I will re-add the general advice only to ask one question at a time, and to search diligently for similar questions which may already have been asked.

Comment: _Him_ sounds more natural than _he_ because _him_ is the unmarked (default, basic, normal) third person masculine pronoun. _He_ is reserved for fixed phrases, idioms, and and ordinary use as the subject of a tensed clause. _Being a tenacious problem solver_ is not a tensed clause, hence _him_ is the norm. You could get away with _he_ here, because it **is** a subject, but it's still strained. When in doubt, use _him_ (same advice for _me, her, us,_ and _them_).

Comment: I disagree with JL. Generally, personal pronoun subjects of non-finite clauses are accusative or genitive, as in "She insisted on him/his going with her". But in cases where the non-finite clause is functioning as a **supplement**, as it does in your example, the pronoun subject usually appears in the nominative, "he", with accusative "him" a somewhat marginal alternant in informal style. This kind of construction is the only one where we find a nominative subject in a non-finite clause; it belongs to a fairly formal style, and hence the informal accusative form "him" is unlikely.

Comment: Interesting perspectives from both of you, John Lawler and BillJ. I would like to know which version of the sentence Pullum and Huddleston favour (I presume such cases must be there in their seminal work CGEL)

Comment: 'Him' is perhaps the fourth best choice here and 'he' the sixth. @Ram Pillai, in what should be a 'comment', has suggested the best choice. Reasons are mixed register and near-ridiculous stuffiness. But that just pushes back the root questions: _why_  are mixed register and near-ridiculous stuffiness in play? _Why_ are 'But, being a tenacious problem solver, he insisted on going' and 'But, as he was a tenacious problem solver, he insisted on going' so much more idiomatic?

Comment: I think far too much is being made of this, particularly in view of the irrelevant and untimely comments now being posted. If you prefer the accusative @Userabc, then just use it -- it's not ungrammatical. I can tell you, though, that H&P go for the nominative, "him" being informal in a relatively formal supplementary adjunct. In fact, it's because the clause is a supplement, rather then being integrated into the syntactic structure, that the nominative is preferred, while elsewhere one would expect to find the accusative (or genitive).

Comment: NB: We discourage answers in comments, on the whole, although they can be helpful to the OP. All users are at liberty to create answer posts from comments if they wish, and even to gain (or lose) rep on what they think to be worthy of becoming an answer. It's also possible to create a CW answer out of someone else's comment.

Answer (score 1):

> *But he insisted on going, him*/*he being a tenacious problem solver*.

Both forms are possible. However, the accusative is informal and somewhat unlikely, while the construction itself is relatively formal, so there's a clash of styles with the accusative tending to sound out of place here.

If you prefer "him", then go ahead and use it: I just want to point out the stylistic difference.

Regarding your second question. I'm inclined to say that "problem-solver" is a compound noun and hence should be hyphenated. Other examples with a noun + deverbal *er* noun structure include "factory-worker", "window-cleaner", "city-dweller", "store-manager".

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some evidence for your views. Bald assertions do not let anyone judge whether your answers are correct or not.

Comment: I'd say that while  'But he insisted on going, him being a tenacious problem solver' _does_ mix registers improbably, 'But he insisted on going, he being a tenacious problem solver'  sounds so rarefied that it's heading towards a breach of Orwell's Sixth.

Answer (score -1):

But, being a tenacious problem solver, he insisted on going.

The phrase 'being a tenacious problem solver' when used at the start offers clarity, and avoids confusion of agreements like "who is being?"

Comment: 'Him' is wrong because it needs to be in the subjective case, and not objective case. The problem lies not just in re-arranging, but knowing 'why' it is done. :)

Comment: @Userabc "Him" is not actually wrong. The non-finite clause "him being a tenacious problem solver" is an adjunct, and hence the choice is between nominative "he" and accusative "him". However, the accusative is informal and somewhat unlikely, while the construction itself is relatively formal, so the accusative tends to sound out of place here.

Comment: Have you really understood what BillJ has explained?  Comment should follow better understanding. He has said, "the accusative is informal and somewhat unlikely, while the construction itself is relatively formal, so the accusative tends to sound out of place here."  His reply is closer to what I meant.

Comment: @Userabc: This is a prestigious forum; you may choose decent words. Words define people.

Comment: When you two have finished your slanging match... I disagree that _him_ sounds more natural. As _he_ is the subject of the sentence, I don't thing you even need another pronoun.

Comment: You are, perhaps, KingSath (? I vaguely remember) who was expelled from ELU for poor language use. It needs to be verified.

Comment: I agree that this is more natural sounding than either of OP's suggestions. But in sidestepping the issue, this answer also fails to directly address OP's actual question.

Answer (score -4):

One method of approaching such questions is to construct partial sentences, substituting nouns and pronouns.

> John insisted on going.

> He insisted on going.

No one would dispute that these are both grammatically correct. “John” and “He” are the subjects of the sentence.

> John, being a tenacious problem solver, insisted on going.

Is this grammatically correct? Yes: “being a…” is in apposition to or describes John. If so,

> He, being a tenacious problem solver, insisted on going.

must be correct.

Now the example sentence just involves — perhaps unnecessary, or perhaps emphatic — repetition of “John”, which in both fragments above is replaced by “he”, *not* “him”. Therefore, in standard English (rather than non-standard English, which may be common in certain sections of particular societies and the possible reason for the poster’s confusion) the sentence should read:

> But **he** insisted on going, **he** being a tenacious problem solver.

There is no grammatical justification for changing the second (repeating) pronoun to the object/accusative case.

Comment: I don't think an answer based on 50 yr-old school grammar is helpful. Where the non-finite clause is in adjunct function, there most definitely is a choice between an accusative or nominative pronoun subject. The choice should take account of formality, though, as I mentioned in my comments/answer. What evidence do you have for it being a matter of dialect? As far as the possible compounding of "problem+solver" is concerned, there are tests for determining whether a word is a compound or a syntactic construction, none of which include ambiguity.

Comment: @BillJ — I was not referring to the Grammar I learned 50 years or more ago. I am referring to a method for making a grammatical choice that seems valid. It seems to work in giving what you call the "formal" alternative. I have deleted my responses to the OP but I do not recall suggesting "him" was dialect and that was not my meaning in this case. If one is allowed to refer to differences in education, I meant that poorly educated people often disregard the rules of grammar followed by the educated. I assumed that the poster was interested in those latter rules, rather than social usage.

Answer (score -4):

> But he insisted on going, him/he being a tenacious problem solver.

Both versions are incorrect and non-idiomatic. (As an aside “tenacious problem solver” sounds like a calque from another language.)

The intended meaning is:

But he insisted on going, **as he was/is/claimed to be, etc.,** a tenacious problem solver.

It should be

“But he insisted on going, **his** being a tenacious problem solver.” Or “Being a tenacious problem solver, he insisted on going.

*"[**his**] being a tenacious problem solver"* is a noun clause acting as a free modifier of “but he insisted on going.”